# The html web paga changes in different browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows

I have created a html webpage for my school project . I saw a weird thing happening . The webpage when viewed in IE was a different from the one that was viewed in Chrome . The webpage , when viewed in IE was different and when viewed in Chrome was different . I have not yet tried out Fire fox .Please help me guys .

Comment: There are some inconsistencies between different browsers. Especially old IE version tend to mess things up. Try to describe your problem with more detail and attach some code, if you want us to help.

Comment: Use the standard CSS/CSS3 which is compatible to all latest browsers

Comment: i may add the code today .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well just try using your web page on a more advanced web browser. I hope like chrome ,

Answer (score 2):

Does your webpage include a `<!DOCTYPE>`? This is the number one most likely cause of major differences between IE and other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Some CSS styling the webpages use are very browser specific. The web-page you are trying to view may have those, and hence appear different in different browsers.